# Mysql Laravel: Storing image links as array or create a new table with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm creating a database of 'clubs', and each club can have more than one image associated to it in the form of links. Now I'm wondering if it is a good idea to store the image links as array ['https://foo.bar/image1.jpg','https://foo.bar/image2.jpg'] or should I create another table with foreign key just for the images.

Which approach is better and why?

Comment: Well, I think it depends on what you want to do with that data once is stored. Will you want to request just the club's images but not the club it self? Order them? Soft deletes? Other fields besides the link? I don't have much experience storing JSON data, but most of the time I did it, I ended up creating a dedicated table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a separate table, it is better/faster to delete  a single image later on and also there is no limit on how many you can store because there is a row limit in mysql you can check more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html).

You will have an image object that will know how to display the image, so that responsibility would not belong to the club.